# Webfont Rendering Strangely (looks like ransom note)

Tags: css, webfonts

I am having some very specific browser/OS issues with webfonts where the fonts are half rendering. Best way to explain it is to show it (the "I" and "s" are off):

[image]

The issue has been reported on  Chrome on Windows 10 and FireFox 51.0.1 on Win10.

I thought this was a solution https://codestag.com/fix-google-chrome-web-fonts-issue/ but didn't work.

I am serving webfonts through https://www.typography.com/cloud/welcome/
Live site is http://www.underconsideration.com/brandnew/about.php

I had never seen a problem like this… all "webfont render problem" posts address jaggedness, blurriness, or weird cropping but this is a different beast. Any ideas?

Comment: This really just looks like a faulty font that does not support these specific characters. A broken font-file wouldn't work at all, and this result looks like it's able to do about half. It's also _consistently_ missing letters (I, d, p, r, s) throughout the text, so it is most likely a broken font.

Comment: I would start by looking at how you are embedding the font files. What font file formats are you using? Not all browser know to render all font files. Have a [`look here`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp) to see what browsers support what formats. Generally speaking, if you provide `.woff` and `.otf`, you're fine. But you should also include `.woff2` as it's a ***major*** boost in rendering performance for browsers that support it. Even if provided by a third party, you can still inspect using your browser to see what files are loaded.

Comment: Now, that I think of it, I did have a similar issue about an year ago. It was related to fonts being already installed and being faulty on the target machine and they didn't load (because the system thought they're not needed). I found a way to force the font-files to be loaded from web, I think I did it by renaming the font, but i'm not 100% sure. Best way to check is rename the font and see if the problem still occurs.

Comment: I recreated the font files and that seems to have fixed it, based on a limited windows emulation extension. I don't have Windows so I can't test it properly.